# Rendering video in game engine with dynamic FPS

Tags: algorithm, video, time, frame, frame-rate

I'm trying to render a pre-exported video in my game engine and have stumbled upon problems when trying to schedule frames. Namely, while the video is exported at fixed FPS, the engine has a dynamic frame rate (which may be higher or lower than the video's). When trying to choose which video frame to render in the current engine frame, my algorithms keep running into edge cases which ruins either the speed of the video or the distribution of the video frames.

I'm aware at this point that there is probably no algorithm which will run perfectly in all situations, but there are three situations which are likely to happen during the runtime and should be covered by the algorithm:

1. Arbitrary stable frame rate in the engine, with a ~5% margin of error. (For example, if average frame time is 33.333ms, all of the frame durations would fall within the 31.6666ms - 35ms range.)
2. Arbitrary semi-stable frame rate, with <5% of the frames having a duration outside the margin of error.
3. Stable frame rate which can change to a different stable frame rate during the video playback.

During these 3 situations, the following should hold true:

1. When observing over arbitrary period of time, speed at which the video renders is the same as the speed at which video would render at its original FPS.
2. When observing over arbitrary period of time, during which engine had a stable frame rate, frame distribution should be balanced.

Having all this in mind, I've tried 2 solutions which didn't yield good results even with a couple of heuristics.

1. A really naive solution in which delta time of the current frame is multiplied by the frame rate, the result is rounded and video playback is advanced by that many frames. While this solution works perfectly at some frame rates, the speed difference is too high at others. For example, if the video is at 60FPS and engine renders at 30FPS, every engine frame will advance the video playback by 2 frames, which is perfect. However, even at ~39 FPS, due to the rounding effect, the playback will still only be advanced by 2 frames in each engine frame, resulting in the decreased speed of the video.
2. A timeline-based solution where we keep track of the accumulated duration of all previous engine frames. Summing that and the duration of the current engine frame, then rounding it to the nearest multiple of the video frame duration, we get the approximate video frame which should be rendered in the engine. This solution balances the video speed perfectly, but there's many edge cases where the frame distribution becomes very unbalanced, leading to stuttering in the video. Using the same example as earlier, with video at 60FPS and engine at 30FPS, there's an edge case where one frame with duration of ~41.66666ms will lead to the situation where the video frames are advanced as (1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3....) instead of (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2...).

I guess my questions are: Is there a problem with known algorithms and heuristics which could be reduced to this one? If not, is there a nice heuristic which would yield better results in the 3 situations I've described above?

Comment: I like your question, but I'm not qualified to answer it... Just thinking it through... I would consider taking the shortcut and force the engine framerate to something that works nicely with the video in question when I need to display it... if you need to display a video all the time this probably won't be very efficient. If it's a full screen video, I wouldn't use the engine at all.

Comment: @rfmodulator Unfortunately, the way I've imagined it, the video is supposed to play as a UI element once the user hovers over certain buttons. As for the engine, I might decide to go that route (forcing constant FPS while the video is being shown), but I would really like to hear if there is a nice way to resolve this without having to change the engine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your timeline-based algorithm is pretty close.  I think you just need to define your desires mathematically.

For each frame selection, we could consider two kinds of error.  Let *w* be the difference between the wall clock time when the selected frame will show, and the time when it *should* show according to the video frame rate.  Let *d* be the error in the difference between the show times of the selected frame and the previously shown frame.

Define the relative weights *A* and *B* of these errors, and then select the frame that minimizes *Aw<sup>2</sup> + Bd<sup>2</sup>*

Comment: I had trouble defining the problem and the goal mathematically and your answer has helped me immensely. However, your definition of the second error still leaves room for imbalance in edge cases where frames should be skipped intermittently. I've changed the second definition to include the error in the difference between the show times of the selected frame and all the other previously shown frames. Now the algorithm handles edge cases in a proper way, and unwrapping the formula (if we don't want to weigh each difference separately) saves me from having to store delta time for each frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could take your second approach and apply some simple smoothing, e.g. advance your frame by the average of the last two values, always rounding down and propagating error forward, i.e. when the sum is an odd number and you round down to get an integer you add 1 to the next sum to balance it out.

So 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3... would produce 2, 2, 2, 2, 2... and 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 would produce 2, 3, 2, 3, 2... etc

pseudo-code:

```
int prevValue = 0
int error = 0;
bool firstValue = true;
int getNextValue(int value)
{
    if(firstValue)
    {
        prevValue = value;
        firstValue = false;
    }
    int sum = value + prevValue + error;
    error = sum % 2; 
    prevValue = value;
    return sum / 2; // integer division
}
```